# Replacing nav menu link with image that matches logo image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, nav

I have an existing site that I created with a typical 200px x 300 px logo and then a nav menu to the right of it. The last link in the menu links to a partner site.

They've decided they want to put a 200x300 logo in place of their text link, so my nav menu would essentially be bookended by matching logo images. I'm semi familiar with putting an image in for a nav link and it's a current wordpress install.

I have custom CSS in this wP install, but would that be the best practice for this? Just using an image in CSS for that specific link?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking without providing any code. If you want to replace a text link with an image, you need to edit the HTML not the CCS. Inside the <a> tag, replace the text with <img src="/path/to/your/logo.jpg"/>

Comment: Thank you, I knew there would be a few ways but I didn't want to use a background property in CSS.

Comment: If you google it, you will find answers that you can add css class on a menu item and use css to customize it. Wordpress menu is a bit tricky to customize so you may end up using css if you want a quick fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a class="vasile" href="http://partnerwebsite.com"> Vasile.com </a>
In CSS file add this:
a.vasile {
background-image:url(http://imagethatyouwantotuse.com/image.jpg);
display:block;
height:?px;
width:?px;}
```